# How can I edit the legend in an excel pivot chart 2010

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, pivot-table

How can I edit the text of the legend in an Excel pivot chart in office 2010?
It is a workbook that only has a pivot chart with no pivot table.
Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every Pivot Chart has a data source. Edit the data source to adjust the text in the chart's legend. As far as I know, the source for a pivot chart can only live in the same workbook. The data source can be on a hidden sheet, though. I have not found a way to move a pivot chart to a different workbook and keep the connection to the data source alive. If a pivot chart is cut and pasted into a different workbook, the data connection is severed. In that case, the series labels can be changed like in any other chart, i.e. by editing the series.

Comment: Thanks for that. I have copied and pasted the pivot chart and the pivot table to different worksheets.

Comment: Ah. Well, the column headers in the pivot table have the text that shows in the pivot chart legend, i.e. the series name. Edit that in the pivot table and the change will reflect in the pivot chart.